# How to solve Leetcode SQL Find the Team Size using PARTITION BY?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Employee Table:
+-------------+------------+
| employee_id | team_id    |
+-------------+------------+
|     1       |     8      |
|     2       |     8      |
|     3       |     8      |
|     4       |     7      |
|     5       |     9      |
|     6       |     9      |
+-------------+------------+
Result table:
+-------------+------------+
| employee_id | team_size  |
+-------------+------------+
|     1       |     3      |
|     2       |     3      |
|     3       |     3      |
|     4       |     1      |
|     5       |     2      |
|     6       |     2      |
+-------------+------------+
Employees with Id 1,2,3 are part of a team with team_id = 8.
Employees with Id 4 is part of a team with team_id = 7.
Employees with Id 5,6 are part of a team with team_id = 9.
```

This is the question from Leetcode website.

My Query is:

```
select employee_id, count(employee_id) OVER(PARTITION BY team_id) team_size 
from employee
```

What is wrong with my query, or how to solve this question using PARTITION?

Comment: Your query looks fine. What is the problem with it?

Comment: @GMB Just noticed that `:~|`

Comment: Maybe they want `COUNT(*)` instead of `COUNT(employee_id)`, but the outcome is really the same.

Comment: Perhaps Leetcode doesn't recognize window functions.

Answer (score 1):

Use `COUNT` as an analytic function:

```
SELECT
    employee_id,
    team_id,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY team_id) AS team_size
FROM Employee
ORDER BY employee_id;
```